# Memory Leaks in StatefulKnowledgeSession in Drools 6.5.0.Final

Tags: java, memory-leaks, drools

I've been trying to locate a memory leak problem in my application which uses Drools 6.5.0.Final as one of its core components.

I'm not sure whether it's really a Drools problem. To support my assumption, I wrote the following rule and deployed it into Drools.

```
package test
import memleak.MemoryLeak;
import event.SetupEvent;

rule "Memory Leak"
    no-loop true
    when
        $event: SetupEvent();
    then
       new MemoryLeak().leak();
end
```

In the leak() method, it simply creates a 200MB byte array.

```
package memleak;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MemoryLeak {

    private static final int _10MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    public List<MemObject> leak() {
        int loop = 20;
        List<MemObject> byteArr = new ArrayList<MemObject>(loop);
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; ++i) {
            byteArr.add(new MemObject(_10MB));
        }

        return byteArr;
    }
}

class MemObject {

    private byte[] contents;

    public MemObject(int size) {
        contents = new byte[size];
    }
}
```

After I used the SetupEvent to fire the rule, I called the "dispose" method of the KieSession. But what I found out is that the memory that I allocated before was not freed.

Also, I've tried to use the "insert" method in the rule to insert the byte array into the session. It didn't seem to be freed either.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Steven

Comment: Stateful session?

Comment: Yep. Stateful sessions. Any idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely memory will be freed after [System.gc()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-gc) in your case.
You can free memory of the stateful session by for using [delete](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch07.html#d0e6171)

---

Using your domain objects and the rule, here is the test which inserts 10K `SetupEvent`s.

```
@DroolsSession(resources = "classpath:/test.drl", log = false)
public class PlaygroundTest {

    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
            drools.insertAndFire(new SetupEvent());
    }
}
```

I'm not even retracting `SetupEvent`s, they do not have fields, size is pretty small. Test is running ~5.5 mins. Show me memory leak...

[image]

200M memory allocation is not cpu free operation, it takes 32ms in average on my machine. Test is doing memory allocation and garbage collection...

[image]

Could you create a test which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. The `delete` method does remove the fact I don't need anymore. But that means I have to delete all the facts manually. What I want is to free all the memory space that been used by a certain session that I will no longer use. Besides, If I allocate memory but don't `insert` the corresponding fact into the session   (as what exactly what I demonstrated above), there's no chance for me to do a manual invocation of `delete`. Under such circumstances, is `System.gc()` the only way to free the memory?

Comment: Java decides when to clean the memory, I think there is an issue with your test. You are monitoring memory consumption, but you must not expect jvm to clear memory at once objects are no longer used. That was my point when I mentioned gc jvm hint. When you insert object into working memory new strong reference is definitely created. When you retract object strong reference must be vanished or you have found bug in drools. If you don't want to delete object but you want to dispose all session is fine too. But your expectation is wrong what dispose must cleanup all strong references.

Comment: While this may be true, but most likely strong references will be cleaned up when session object will be cleaned up. So again your test is not valid most likely. Another point, when you create the object but don't create a reference to it, it is subject for gc at once. I'm wondering why would you need to dispose the session. Your test does not reflect the problem most likely. Proper direction would be to create a test which reproduces OOE, publish it here and then we can implement (advise) and 'measure' the fix.

Comment: I totally agree with you. An object with no reference is subject to GC. But that's what's exactly been confusing me. Theoretically, the memory allocated by `new MemoryLeak().leak();` should be cleaned soon after the object is created because it's not referred to by any other objects. But the fact is even after a couple of hours, I could still find it in the heap space and the memory usage does not seem to come down. I'll try if I could find more clues for this and be back again. Thanks for your answers.